# getData of file in Symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to retrieve the data from my csv file sent via the form but the result is null.

Form :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('submitFile', FileType::class, array('label' => 'File to Submit'))
        ->add('add', SubmitType::class)->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                    $filename = $form['submitFile']->getData();
                dump($filename); exit; // i have result of null here
                $header = NULL;
                $data = array();
                $delimiter = ';';
                if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
                        if(!$header) {
                            $header = $row;
                        } else {
                            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                        }
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                }
                return $data;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to dump `$form->getData()`? 
and also check that you file does not exceed file maximum size defined in php.ini

Comment: i have the same result of null 
array:1 [▼
  "submitFile" => null
]

Comment: check that your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`